# Django Index not took in account for existing table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I use existing mysql table with Django Rest Framework.
On a big mysql table, a simple select request in phpmysql tooks 10 seconds without index. With an index on a field, it tooks 3ms. So I added manualy the index with phpMysql, but Django still takes 10 seconds to execute the request and dosn't see the new index.
I added `db_index=True` in my field in models.py. But make migration didn't see any update on my already existing models, and the speed is still 10s. (Any updates on tables created by django work very well) 
I decided to remove my index manualy with phpmysql, and I created by my self a 0002_initial.py file with this code :

> from django.db import migrations, models
>
> class Migration(migrations.Migration):
>
> ```
> dependencies = [
>     ('tutorials', '0001_initial'), # or last mig
> ]
>
> operations = [
>     migrations.RunSQL("CREATE INDEX idx_last_name ON crm_users (us_last_name(64))")
> ]
> ```

I ran migrate, and django creates the index in the table. But Django still takes 10s to perform one select on the indexed field and dosn't use the mysql index.

My question : Where and how can I say to django to use indexes for existing table not created by Django ? Thank you very much !

Comment: You don't have to, normally this is done by the database itself. Are you sure that there is an index on the column? What if you perform `DESC crm_users`? Do you see an index?

Comment: When I perform DESC crm_users i see the index create by the RunSQL. This index works well in phpmysql

Comment: exactly what query do you run. If you fetch *all* `user` objects, then it can indeed take ~10s, so I suspect something is wrong with the query.

Comment: profils = profils.filter(us_last_name__icontains=name).using('crm') and then I access with the url localhost:8080/api/profils?name=XXXX and the XXXX only get 8 results

Comment: What is your exact query generated by Django ORM? have you checked with exact query you are running
MyModel.objects.get().query , using EXPLAIN statement.
Database chooses query execution plan and this is not related directly to Django ( except part where Django ORM generates query)
Depending on your query ( ordering, etc) database decides on execution plan and might not use index

Comment: @PatriceG: but `__icontains` can *not* make use of the index, even if it is a prefix-tree or a suffix tree. FOr a full match, you can use `profils.filter(us_last_name=name)`, but for substrings, one has to check line-by-line.

Comment: the generated sql is Select [all_the_fields] where us_last_name like %[Look-Up-Name]% And when I test in phpmysql with the % in takes 10s, and without 3ms... This is why it is so slow... Yes the index is not used with like %__%. Thank you you answer my question ! But it not solves my issue, because I need to perform an autocomplete fields on a large set of data... If you have any ideas ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @PatriceG: normally this is done by "preparing" the values in the database. One makes *n-grams* of small parts that are elements. See for example how *Haystack* does this: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/v2.7.0/pdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

> ```
> profils = profils.filter(us_last_name__icontains=name).using('crm')
> ```

Can ***not* make use of the index**.

Indeed you here aim to perform a *substring* lookup. For example `'bar'` will match if the column contains `'foobarqux'`. There are no indexes that support this. A prefix-tree or a suffix-tree can for example match strings that start or end with a given string respectively.

For a substring, that is not an option. One can define certain sophisticated indexes, but those would require large overhead in inserting, updating and removing elements, and require memory that is relatively large compared to the actual data stored. Therefore it is unlikey that a database will implement these. An ideal index is usually fast in both searching *and* updating, and often consumes a small amount of memory compared to the real table, since otherwise loading the index would take already significant amount of time.

A query that could make use of the index is this:

```
profils = profils.filter(us_last_name=name).using('crm')
```

But then of course you perform an exact match.

This has nothing to do with Django. If you try in a database shell to perform a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM crm_users WHERE us_last_name LIKE '%bar%'
```

it will take approximately the same amount of time.

In search engines, one often "prepares" data in the database, by collecting [*n-grams* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-grams_for_approximate_matching) that allows then to filter fast on the input. A package like [**`django-haystack`** [readthedocs]](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io) might help with this.

Comment: You absolutely right ! Index wasn't taken acount because of the __icontains. So I changed with __istartswith :  profils = profils.filter(us_last_name__istartswith=name)  And now the index works, and all my rest execution is 200ms  and it can fit with the auto-complete, I am creating, on the last name field. Thank you very much Willem for your help !